# Quero passar um parâmetro que está na main para uma função e efetuar um cálculo, exercício de ponteiro e função, como faço?

Tags: c

Olá, boa tarde.

Tenho um ponteiro na main que aponta para uma variável (variável "ex1"), e eu preciso fazer com cálculo com ele em outra função... o que eu tenho agora tá assim...

```
main() {

  código...
  código...
  float calculo;

  if (contador > 1) {
    ponteiro = &ex1;
    /* o que quero fazer abaixo... */
    calculo = funcao(calculo);
    printf("Resultado: %f \n",funcao(calculo));
  }
}

void valor_r_ex(float *n3) {
  printf("Inf. o 1º valor: ");
  scanf("%f", n3);
  /* primeiro valor porque ex1 na main vai fazer um calculo com o valor digitado acima... */
}

funcao() {
  float m, calc;
  valor_r_ex(&m);
  /*abaixo é o que eu quero fazer mas não sei como... */
  calc = m + ex1;
  return calc;
}
```

Comment: Não coloque o código como imagem. Em vez disso adicione-o à pergunta como texto e formate com o botão `{}`

Comment: Esse não é o código verdadeiro, é apenas um exemplo de como é

Comment: [Leia aqui porque não deve colocar código como imagem](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/5483/manual-de-como-n%C3%83o-fazer-perguntas/5485#5485). Em relação à pergunta, a sua questão é como definir a função para que receba um ponteiro ? ou no quê especificamente?

Comment: Ah, entendi, não sabia dessa sobre a imagem, desculpe.

Comment: Eu preciso passar um valor da main para uma função, essa função faz o cálculo, e depois na main eu chamo uma função apenas para printar o resultado desse cálculo

Comment: Coloque o código como texto para que seja facil a qualquer pessoa responder com o código da sua pergunta. Independentemente disso você já está a usar uma função que recebe um ponteiro, a `valor_r_ex(float *n3)`. Qual a real dificuldade mesmo, uma vez que seria o mesmo principio?

Answer (score 1):

Bom basicamente pelo o que eu entendi você quer saber como passar uma variável por parâmetro em C, é importante saber que em C há duas maneiras de se passar variáveis por parâmetro em uma função, existe a passagem por valor, e a passagem por referencia.

Mas antes de explicar qual a diferença entre assas duas passagens é importante dar uma breve explicação sobre função.
As funções devem ser declaradas antes do main, e para declara-las é bem parecido com uma variável basta fazer o seguinte: escolha o tipo de retorno,  nome da função e parâmetro.
o tipo de retorno é como o nome já diz, é o tipo de dado que sua função irá retornar, o nome da função, é o nome que você utilizará para chamar a função, e os parâmetros, são os dados que você terá que passar para sua função, para ela trabalhar com.

Para declarar os parâmetros basta ter em mente as seguintes coisas, qual o tipo de dado que terei que utilizar para minha função trabalhar, qual serão os nomes e quantas variáveis serão necessárias, ex:

```
int calculaMultiplicacao ( int a, int b )
{
    return a * b;
}
```

e

```
void calculaMultiplicacao ( int a, int b, int* R )
{
    *R = a * b;
}
```

Essas são dois exemplos de funções, ambas fazem a mesma coisa, mas foram implementadas de forma diferentes, no primeiro caso note que o retorno da função é `int`, isto se dá porquê o valor que a função irá retornar é um inteiro, dai temos o nome, e de pois os parâmetros, note que no primeiro caso é pedido duas variáveis por parâmetro, ambas são do tipo inteiro, e perceba que sem essas duas variáveis a função não funcionaria, pois são elas que são necessária para a função fazer o que ela tem que fazer. Então sempre quando for fazer um parâmetro pense nisso, qual serão os dados necessário que terei que passar para essa função para ela funcionar.

Já no segundo exemplo temos o seguinte, o retorno é do tipo `void`, isto porquê não há retorno, e são pedidas três variáveis no parâmetro duas para trabalhar com e uma terceira para receber o resultado, por isso o retorno é desnecessário pois o resultado será passado por referencia e não por retorno, agora você estará pronto para entender passagem por referencia e passagem por valor.

Passagem por valor, como o nome já diz você passa um valor para uma função este pode ser dado diretamente nos parâmetro ou por meio de uma variável, ex:

Vamos supor que temos uma função que multiplica dois números inteiros qualquer, então a passagem por por valor na função main seria a seguinte.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int calculaMultiplicacao ( int a, int b )
{
    return a * b;
}

int main ()
{
    int a, b;

    scanf(" %i %i", &a, &b);

    printf("\nO resultado eh: %i\n", calculaMultiplicacao(a, b)); /*    Note que eu estou pasando os dois
                                                                        valores que estão em a e b  */

    return 0;
}
```

Note que quando fazemos isso, estamos passando apenas os valores que estão nas variáveis `a` e `b`, um teste interessante para você entender melhor o que eu quero dizer com isso é o seguinte, dentro da função `calculaMultiplicacao` experimente mudar o valor de `a` e `b`, e depois imprima `a` e `b` na main, você irá notar que o valor que aparecerá será o valor que foi atribuído no `scanf`, e não o que foi modificado na função, isto é por causa que o neste caso de passagem, o que é passado é a penas o valor e não a "variável".

Explicando de uma maneira melhor, o que seu programa faz com isso é o seguinte, no momento que você chama a função e passa a variável `a` e `b`, o programa cria outras duas variáveis `a1` e `b1` (note que coloquei este nome apenas para não confundir, pois os nomes das variáveis seria o mesmo que foi declarado nos parâmetros da função) e iguala os valores delas com os das variáveis passadas , `a1 = a`, `b1 = b`, mas uma variável não tem nada a ver com a outra, por isso se você alterar o valor de `a` e `b` na função `calculaMultiplicacao`, isso não alterará o verdadeiro valor de `a` e `b` que estão na main.

Passagem por valor também nos permite fazer outra abordagem, já que o que interessa é apenas o valor, e não a variável a gente não precisa necessariamente passar variáveis no parâmetro da função podendo fazer o seguinte:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int calculaMultiplicacao ( int a, int b )
{
    return a * b;
}

int main ()
{
    printf("\nO resultado eh: %i\n", calculaMultiplicacao(5, 6)); /*    Note que eu estou pasando os dois
                                                                        valores diretamente.  */

    return 0;
}
```

Note que estou passando dois valores diretamente, isto é possível, porque como já explicado anteriormente a função irá criar duas variáveis `a` e `b`, e irá igualar o valor delas aos que foi passado, ficando `a = 5, b = 6,` (neste caso é claro).

A segunda forma é a passagem por referência, esta se dá por meio da passagem de uma certa região da memória, que utilizaremos para alterar e ou guardar um valor, com base nisso é importante saber o seguinte um ponteiro, é uma variável que a ponta para uma região da memória, então no momento que você for declarar sua função, a variável a ser passada por referência terá de ser um ponteiro, ex:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void calculaMultiplicacao ( int a, int b, int* R )
{
    *R = a * b;
}

int main ()
{
    int a, b, R;

    scanf(" %i %i", &a, &b);

    calculaMultiplicacao(a, b, &R); /*  Note que pelo fato de R ser uma variável normal, no momento que
                                        eu a passo por parâmetro, eu coloco o & pois estou passando o enderço
                                        de memória de R */

    printf("\nO resultado eh: %i\n", R);

    return 0;
}
```

Note que o `R` é passado com o `&`, isto se dá ao fato de que `R` é uma variável normal, e como necessitamos passar uma região da memória para ser alterada, então colocamos o `&`, pois assim passamos o endereço da variável `R`, neste caso não podemos passar um valor direto (não no lugar de `R`, mas no de `a` e `b` ainda pode), pois necessita ser uma região da memória.

Outra coisa importante de lembrar é que caso `R` fosse um ponteiro no main, não necessitaria passa-lo no parâmetro com o `&`, pois um ponteiro já direciona para uma região da memória.

Aqui está um link de um gif que pode ajuda-lo a compreender a diferença entre passagem por valor e passagem por referência [clique aqui e vá para o gif](https://devblog.drall.com.br/wp-content/uploads/2016/06/pass-by-reference-vs-pass-by-value-animation.gif), bom qualquer duvida é só perguntar, espero ter ajudado ;).

Answer (score 0):

Você deve passar a variável `ex1` como parâmetro da função, em seguida, a utilize como desejado.

- Não se esqueça de declarar a função e seu retorno;
- Caso a sua função retorne um ponteiro também deve ser especificado.

Ex:

```
int *funcao(int *ponteiro);

main(){
 ...
 resultado = funcao(ponteiro);
 ...
}

int *funcao(int *endereco_inicio)
{
  meu_ponteiro = *endereco_inicio;
  ...
  return resultado;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Aparentemente a pergunta é "como passar um parâmetro ponteiro para uma função".

Solução: usar o operador "&" para passar o ponteiro na chamada da função, e usar o operador "*" para pegar o valor da variável acessada peolo ponteiro.

Exemplo:

```
#include <stdio.h>

static double square(double* val)
{
  return *val * *val; // <---
}

int main(void)
{
  double x = 10;
  printf("10 * 10 = %f", square(&x)); // <---
}
```